# WPF MaxWidth Binding for Window not working

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to bind the Maxwidth of my  `Window` instead of setting it in xaml code.

Before it was:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDialogs.GenericWindow"
    x:Name="BaseDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=wpfDialogs:DialogViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    MaxWidth="1280" MaxHeight="600"
    MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
```

I changed the xaml to

```
MaxWidth="{Binding MaximumWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxHeight="{Binding MaximumHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And added to the VM:

```
    public double MaximumHeight
{
  get => mMaxHeight;
  set { mMaxHeight = value; }
}
public double MaximumWidth
{
  get => mMaxWidth;
  set { mMaxWidth = value; }
}
```

The VM is  created and the `DataContext` of the `Window` will be set to the vm.

The setter and getter are both called (Set in the Constructor of the VM and get when the View is created)
But when testing this, I can maximize the window as much as I want to.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Do you get binding errors in Output window? It should work, problem is somewhere else, what you didn't show. See [mcve].

Comment: @Sinatr no binding errors, as is stated above, getter is beeing called

Comment: You've managed to not show us the backer members and their values. You presumably haven't set those when the getter is hit. Because just: private double mMaxWidth = 1280; Makes this work when I tried it. You should, however, always implement inotifypropertychanged on any viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Your properties do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so changes will not be reflected in the UI.

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // ...other view model code.

   private double mMaxHeight;
   private double mMaxWidth;

   public double MaximumHeight
   {
      get => mMaxHeight;
      set
      {
         mMaxHeight = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
   public double MaximumWidth
   {
      get => mMaxWidth;
      set
      {
         mMaxWidth = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```